# Enable checkbox if text field is not empty with inconsistent id

Tags: javascript, jsp, checkbox

Purpose is to have checkboxes disabled when the page loads, and remain greyed out until textbox is filled.

```
<input type="text" name="<%=commentID%>" />
<input type="checkbox" name="<%=SkipID%>" value="N" disabled/>
```

I tried to do something like

```
<input type="text" name="<%=commentID%>" onkeyup="userTyped('<%=SkipID%>') />

function userTyped(commen){
    if(this.value.length > 0){
        document.getElementById(commen).disabled=false;
    }else{
        document.getElementById(commen).disabled=true;
    }
 }
```

But it did not work. I am assuming because of the inconsistency of the name, but I have to have that.

Comment: You'll get a better response if you create an example of your problem on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net).

Comment: The problem is that the value is not contant. Some logic in my code provides that Id, so I can provide that in jsFiddle

Comment: you can substitute fake data in. Your problem sounded like a purely browser-based problem, so putting a test-bed together in pure HTML/JS in jsFiddle is a good idea for yourself, even if you don't post it to SO. Glad you got it sorted in the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't given id to your html elements and is trying to use `getElementById`, which will return `null`. Javascript engine will not be able to set **disabled** attribute of `null`. Try setting **id** attribute, for elements as given below.

Also in your userTyped function you are referencing `this`. `this` here is the `window` object and not the input element. You need to pass the reference to input element to make this work, like this `onkeyup="userTyped('<%=SkipID%>', this)"`

Please find a possible correction below:

```
<input type="text" name="<%=commentID%>" id="<%=commentID%>" onkeyup="userTyped('<%=SkipID%>', this)" />
<input type="checkbox" name="<%=SkipID%>" id="<%=SkipID%>" value="N" disabled/>

/** commen is the id
  * e is the input element
  **/
function userTyped(commen, e){
    if(e.value.length > 0){
        document.getElementById(commen).disabled=false;
    }else{
        document.getElementById(commen).disabled=true;
    }
 }
```

jsFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/deepumohanp/dGS9H/

Comment: userTyped was to check if a user type into the text field. What's the reason it belongs in checkbox? Also, it does not work :/

Comment: @sayhaha that was a typo. userTyped should be in text field as you have given. if that is not working, can you give what error you are getting?

Comment: Message: 'this.value.length' is null or not an object

Comment: So I edited if statement to  if(this.value != null) ... no more error but checkbox is still disabled after text field is filled

Comment: 'this' inside onkeyup event is the 'window' object and not input element. that's why you got this error. I have given a possible correction in the answer.